# In Azure, where does the cscfg file come from?

Tags: azure

So in Azure, I created a cloud service, and now I want to upload a deployment. It asks for a package (sure, that's easy, a zip file) and a configuration file (.cscfg file). I understand that the .cscfg file is supposed to define the roles, network configuration, etc.

But I don't have a cscfg file. Where are they supposed to originate? Do I have to write one by hand? The documentation for that is [substandard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758710.aspx) at best. Is there any way to generate one? Or do a deployment somehow that bypasses this step? My approach must be wrong on some level (unless I really do have to write one by hand, but I somehow doubt that is a typical case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either rely on Visual Studio to create it or manually create with command line tools.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15658

You can also create using msbuild:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh535755.aspx

Comment: haven't tried but here's tools 4 mac|linux: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2012/06/07/windows-azure-command-line-tool-for-mac-and-linux.aspx

Comment: also: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/how-to-guides/command-line-tools/

Comment: Outside of those tools, the cspkg is just a zip file following a certain layout.  Crack it open and have a look ...